# Login Always Opens Web Dialog Even Though Native Microsoft Apps are Installed [ms graph try Login With Shared Accounts If Possible]

Tags: android, microsoft-graph-api, adal, azureportal, broker

I have integrated the ms graph sdk for authentication but it always open in browser to authenticate,  Can we do the ms graph auth with already installed outlook app or azure app in android without opening browser [same like google account chooser]

Answer (score 0):

Are you using MSAL as this is the supported Android/JAVA library here. MSAL allows easier sharing of identity between apps for instance. https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android

There is more details on single sign on here too https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/authorization-agents